# Pip package installs successfully through Conda.yml pip but not setup.cfg pip

Tags: pip, conda, python-packaging, conda-forge

I am trying to port a simple Conda `.yml` file to a pip packaging `setup.cfg` file.

The Conda file looks like this:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - pip=22.3.1
  - python=3.10.8
  - hydra-core=1.1
  - pip:
      - torch==1.13.1
      - torchvision==0.14.1
      - torchaudio==0.13.1
      - pandas==1.5.3
      - gym==0.25.1
      - ale-py==0.7.5
```

These pip packages are able to be installed, no problem. But when I include them in a pip packaging setup.cfg file like so:

```
install_requires =
    torch==1.13.1,
    torchvision==0.14.1,
    torchaudio==0.13.1,
    pandas==1.5.3,
    gym==0.25.1,
    ale-py==0.7.5,
```

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.13.1 (from package_test) (from versions: 2.0.0, 2.0.1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.13.1`

In fact, many of these distributions inexplicably can't be found.

I was expecting the pip packages to install.

Comment: Which Python version? Which operating system? Which CPU architecture?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.